# How to style correctly in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I started very recently to study/practicing with HTML, typescript, CSS and angular5, and I'm developing a test app to try what I've learned so far. But I am a little bit confused on how I can solve this problem:

Basically I need to set the color of the text inside of a  element (the color of the dropdown button text must be different from the one the menu text has).

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
  <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">drop1<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want "drop1" text in white, while the "menu" element text can be of the default color.

Now if I put in the CSS this:

```
ul li a {
  color: white;
}
```

Each text is colored in white. Now I know I can set directly the style property in HTML tag to override the style from CSS, but since I have several dropdown I would like to set everything in the CSS. How can I do it?

Comment: Use a CSS class or ID to the element? At the moment as you say you're targeting all a tags inside li's that belong in an unordered list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `>` css selector using class like

```
ul.navbar-nav>li>a
```

It will selects all `<a>` elements where the parent is a `.navbar-nav` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ul.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">
        drop1
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
      </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another solution is to use `:not` pseudo class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ul:not(.dropdown-menu)>li>a {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">
        drop1
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
      </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Referece Link

- [child-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)
- [:not() selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: i marked your answer as accepted because, i think it will help me with the readability of the code

Comment: @DanieleSartori I have added a solution with using `:not` pseudo class.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple idea:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
  <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle white-text" role="button" >
      drop1
      <span class="caret">
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With this CSS

```
.white-text {
  color: white!important;
}
```

That means you can utilise this class throughout your site if you need the text to be white

**edit**

If you're worried about using `!important` inside the class you can just remove that, but just ensure that the class is the last entry in the class stack, for example:

`<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle white-text" role="button" >`

rather than

`<a href="#" class="white-text dropdown-toggle" role="button" >`

Comment: Using `!important` is the last thing I would suggest to someone learning the ropes, it's a bad habit to get into

Comment: But it's an override class, it can be done without it as long as it's the last class in the stack

Comment: I tried your solution and of course it work. I just prefer the one that i marked because i think it's more readable for a newbie like me. However i learned also something new with your answer, so thank you

Comment: @DanieleSartori no problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Target the class of your element.

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  color: black; // all your toggle menu (main menu) will have a black color;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white; // all your dropdown menu (sub menu) will have a white color;
}
```

Don't use `!important`;

Answer (score -1):

You myst either use a CSS file or use the `style=""` element inside your HTML tag.

i.e.:
First way: `<button style="color: red; background-color: green;">Log in</button>`

Second way:

HTML file:

```
<button class="mybtn">Log in</button>
```

CSS file:

```
.mybtn {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
}
```

You work like this with all tags and all elements you that want to style.